# How to say that one person shouts after another person?

Tags: phrase-usage

Does it sound normal in English to say that a person shouted/cried/yelled after another person, as in:

Jim packed up quickly and walked away in ignorance and she shouted *after him* that he must never come back again.

Would this sentence be valid in English? And what would you suggest if it wouldn't?
Are there any idioms for this?

This might be a very silly question, I just can't find an example of it on the Internet and can't recall if I have ever heard it in movies. But it sounds ok, given the way "after him/her" is used, say as in "After him! (go after someone).

Comment: It sounds perfectly fine to me....

Comment: It sounds fine, but "at" would be more idiomatic than "after," which has a slightly Southern colloquial sound.  Also "that he must never come back again" definitely strikes my ear as ESL.  A native speaker would say "shouted at him never to come back again."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write:

> Jim packed up quickly and walked away in ignorance and she shouted **at** him that he must never come back again.

*at* because she shouted *in the direction of* Jim.

In another context, you could use *after*:

> Jim packed up quickly and walked away in ignorance and she ran **after** him because she wanted him to stay.

Comment: You can also shout after. I shouted after him as he ran away.